# Is it OK to pause the SharePoint dev VM?

Tags: vmware, pause

We have installed SharePoint 2013 on a VM for development.

At end of day we pause the VM. Does this have any adverse impact on any SharePoint services?

Or is it good practice to shut down the VM ?

Comment: I paused my VM quite often. I think it will cause some dead cache files. You can remove those file follow http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/05/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hardware, pausing your VM could save you significant time over shutting it down.  On my machine with my SSD, pausing takes a matter of seconds while shutting down comes with the added pain of starting up.  Plus, I don’t have to save everything when I pause a VM.  I can leave it in that paused state for days, weeks, or months and it’ll come back like normal.

Source: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/04/sharepoint-and-virtual-machine-vm-performance/

Comment: I am worried about the sudden time shift, could that confuse the SharePoint services, example: Pause on 10 March 2014 at 7:00 PM and resume on 11 March 2014 at 9:00AM; a sudden time shift for active services?

Comment: I paused my vm oftenly, the only issue I encountered that I have to restart the sql services. Other than that nothing strange happens